# PHP Error Changing Bgcolor

Tags: php

I get a error and i dont know why. everything works fine that color changes when you select a radiobutton and press the button. But when you start the website it gives 4 errors called:

Notice: Undefined index: kleur in C:\xampp\htdocs\seb1.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: kleur in C:\xampp\htdocs\seb1.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined index: kleur in C:\xampp\htdocs\seb1.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined index: kleur in C:\xampp\htdocs\seb1.php on line 32

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Vertalingen</title>
    <?php 
            if (!empty($_POST)) {           
                $woord = $_POST["woord"];   
                $vertaal = $_POST["vertaling"];
                    $fp = fopen("seb.txt", "a+");
                    fputs($fp, $woord."\r\n");
                    fputs($fp, $vertaal."\r\n");
                    fclose($fp);
            }

            if(!empty($_GET))   {
                if ($_GET['kleur'] == 'rood')
                    echo '<body bgcolor="red">';
            }

                if ($_GET['kleur'] == 'blauw'){
                    echo '<body bgcolor="blue">';
                }

                if ($_GET['kleur'] == 'geel'){
                    echo '<body bgcolor="yellow">';
                }

                if ($_GET['kleur'] == 'groen'){
                    echo '<body bgcolor="green">';
                }

                if ($_GET['kleur'] == 'oranje'){
                    echo '<body bgcolor="orange">';
                }


        ?>

</head>
<body>

        <form name="woorden" method="post">
        Woord:      <input type="text" name="woord"><br>
        Vertaling:  <input type="text" name="vertaling"><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="Opslaan" value="Opslaan">
        </form>     
        <form method="get">
            Geel:<input type="radio" name="kleur" value="geel"><br>
            Blauw:<input type="radio" name="kleur" value="blauw"><br>
            Rood:<input type="radio" name="kleur" value="rood"><br>
            Oranje:<input type="radio" name="kleur" value="oranje"><br>
            Groen:<input type="radio" name="kleur" value="groen"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="ChangeColor" value="Changecolor">
            <!-- <input type="radio" name=""> -->
            <!-- <input type="radio" name=""> -->
        </form>             
    </body>
</html>
```

*kleur means color
thanks for the help

Comment: use $kleur = isset($_GET['kleur'])?$_GET['kleur']:null;

Answer (score 1):

Its because when you first load the page, your `$_GET['kleur']` variable is empty. Hence, it throws `Undefined Index Notice`.

To handle it add `!empty` check which determines whether variable is empty or not. *[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)*

```
if(!empty($_GET['kleur']))
{
    if ($_GET['kleur'] == 'rood')
        echo '<body bgcolor="red">';
    }

    if ($_GET['kleur'] == 'blauw'){
        echo '<body bgcolor="blue">';
    }
}
```

Comment: or he could first check if the main button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

maybe helpful

```
if(isset($_GET) && isset($_GET['kleur']) && !empty($_GET['kleur'])){
    switch($_GET['kleur']){
        case 'rood':
            echo '<body bgcolor="red">';
        break;
        case 'blauw':
            echo '<body bgcolor="blue">';
        break;
        case 'geel':
            echo '<body bgcolor="yellow">';
        break;
        case 'groen':
            echo '<body bgcolor="green">';
        break;
        case 'oranje':
            echo '<body bgcolor="orange">';
        break;
        default:
            echo '<body bgcolor="red">';
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you missed a few brackets?

```
    if ($_GET['kleur'] == 'rood') { <--this
        echo '<body bgcolor="red">';
    }
    ...
} <-- this
```